# Install R package from tar.gz file and all the package dependencies

Tags: r

I created my own package with the following in the DESCRIPTION file:

```
Imports: 
    dagitty (>= 0.3.1),
    dplyr (>= 1.0.7),
    forcats (>= 0.5.1),
    ggdag (>= 0.2.4),
    ggplot2 (>= 3.3.5),
    magrittr (>= 2.0.1),
    medflex (>= 0.6.7),
    methods (>= 4.1.0),
    nnet (>= 7.3.16),
    stats (>= 4.1.0),
    stringr (>= 1.4.0),
    tibble (>= 3.1.5),
    bnlearn (>= 4.6.1),
    tidyr,
    ROCR,
    rpart,
    rlang
Depends: 
    R (>= 4.1.0),
    SuperLearner (>= 2.0)
Suggests: 
    rmarkdown (>= 2.10),
    knitr (>= 1.36),
    kableExtra (>= 1.3.4),
    recipes (>= 0.1.16)
```

I'm trying to run the following to install my package on a test environment and everything within the imports, depends, and suggests.

I'm running the following:

```
install.packages(pkgs = "testpkg-v0.1.0.tar.gz", 
                 repos = NULL,
                 dependencies = TRUE,
                 type = "source"
)
```

But I get these errors:

```
ERROR: dependencies 'SuperLearner', 'dagitty, 'dplyr', 'forcats', 'ggdag', 'ggplot2', 'magrittr', 'medflex', 'stringr', 'tibble', 'bnlearn', 'tidyr', 'ROCR', 'rlang' are not available for package 'testpkg'
```

Why is this happening? How can I handle this?

Comment: It's happening because you unfortunately R does not support installing package dependencies for a package installed from a source archive (passing `repos = NULL` means that R has no repository in which to search for dependencies, but this value is inferred for source package archives anyway, even if you don't pass it explicitly).

Comment: Is there any way to install package dependencies from a tar.gz file? Or is the workaround just have a user download all the dependencies from looking at the DESCRIPTION?

Comment: Not in base R, as far as I am aware. If you can use packages, then [`remotes::install_local`](https://remotes.r-lib.org/reference/install_local.html) should solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks. I assume using install_local()  for the tar.gz file and using the dependencies = TRUE argument will autmatically install the Imports, Suggest, and Depends?

Comment: I still get the same error using

`remotes::install_local(path = 'testpkg-v0.1.0.tar.gz', dependencies = TRUE)`